# Populating dropdown menu with API data Angular 5 http Client

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular 5 and I read several articles regarding Http calls on Angular 5. Still I have some doubts. I want to populate a drop down with an API and JSON format look like this.

```
    {
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "bus"
    },
    {
      "type": "truck"
    },
    {
      "type": "car"
    }
  ],
  "_metadata": null
}
```

This is what I tried.

App Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {VehicleService } from './vehicle.service'
import { Vehicle } from './vehicle';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';


  _postsArray: Vehicle[];
  result=[];

constructor(private http: HttpClient,
  private vehicleService : VehicleService
){}


ngOnInit():void{
     this.vehicleService.getVehicleData()
     .subscribe(
       resultArray=> this._postsArray=resultArray,
     )
}

}
```

Vehicle Service class

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Vehicle } from './vehicle';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import {Http,Response} from "@angular/http";

import "rxjs/Rx";


@Injectable()
export class VehicleService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    textUrl = "http://test.com/vehicles/types";

     getTenantData(): Observable<Vehicle[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.textUrl)
        .map((response:Response)=>{
            return<Vehicle[]>response.json();
        })
    }


}
```

I'm using a component for dropdown , so html look like this

```
    <label>City</label>
<ng-select [items]="_postsArray"
           bindLabel="name"
           bindValue="id"

           >
</ng-select>
```

I'm getting an error as ERROR TypeError: response.json is not a function. Found and answer in Stack that no need to have json and add only .map(res => res ); there but I'm getting syntax error. Please help me to solve this.